# How to split a wikipedia page into paragraphs using python?

Tags: python, text, split, wikipedia, paragraph

I used the Python wikipedia library to extract the content of a Wikipedia page. I want to process each paragraph of this content (for example count words of each). What is the best way to split wikipedia content into paragraphs?

```py
import wikipedia as wikipedia

def getPage(title):

    content = wikipedia.page(title).content
    #for each paragraph in content do: 
        #...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bad way

The [wikipedia](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) library does not provide such information.

You can see in this example that the returned page content does not contain most layout elements:

```py
import wikipedia
print(wikipedia.page("New York City").content)
```

> "[...] and sports. Home to the headquarters of the United Nations, New York is an important center for international diplomacy.Situated on one of the world's largest natural harbors, [...]"

There certainly are hints of them though, but these are tedious to parse:

- Some paragraph splits like the one above have no spaces after the last period of the previous paragraph;
- Titles use a notation like `== MyTitle ==\n`;
- Newlines are printed.

---

### Defined wikipedia sections

If you're looking for defined sections, try the [wikipediaapi](https://github.com/martin-majlis/Wikipedia-API/) library, which is more active and more complete.

With it, you can get the sections easily:

```py
import wikipediaapi
page_py = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en').page('New_York_City')
print(page_py.sections[0].text)
```

> "In 1664, the city was named in honor of the Duke of York, [...] seized it from the Dutch."

This approach gives you very clean text, but there is no way to identify paragraphs within sections.

---

### Html paragraphs

If however you're looking for paragraphs defined as `<p>...</p>`, you'll need to parse the html and do some cleaning.

Here's one way to achieve that (using [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)):

```py
import bs4
import requests
import unicodedata
import re

def get_paragraphs(page_name):

    r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/{0}'.format(page_name))
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    html_paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')

    for p in html_paragraphs:
        cleaned_text = re.sub('(\[[0-9]+\])', '', unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', p.text)).strip()
        if cleaned_text:
            yield cleaned_text

print(list(get_paragraphs('New_York_City'))[0])
```

> "New York City (NYC), often called simply New York, is the most populous city in the United States. [...] Home to the headquarters of the United Nations, New York is an important center for international diplomacy."

This approach might be the best despite the cleanup not being perfect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete and clear explanation.